# access all your inbox e-mail by code in android

Tags: android

I want to know "how I access mail in my application from mail in-box in my android phone". and also want how to getting only those mails which have an attachment or have some special keyword.

thank you in advance.

I am using GMAIL api http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html

but i did not get all information about mail and mail attachment.

Comment: Good for you.  Have you looked at any documentation, or even tried any *decent* Google searches?

Comment: i am not get inbox-email in my app and i stacked now so please if u have any idea then please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know "how I access mail in my application from mail in-box in my android phone". and also want how to getting only those mails which have an attachment or have some special keyword.

Write your own email client.

Generally speaking, existing mail clients do not have documented and supported APIs to allow arbitrary third-party apps to rummage through the user's mail.

Comment: I use such gmail api like http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html but using this we get only inbox name and number of mail. but actually i want mail content with attachment.

Comment: @sanky: That is not supported, except via public email protocols (e.g,. IMAP) and a suitable JAR (e.g., JavaMail).